# Can Linq AsParallel() dispose of SoapHttpClientProtocol objects prematurely?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, soap-client, plinq, arcgis-server

In an ASP.Net MVC 4 web application that I'm working on. I have one page that basically generates a report by getting data from a SOAP service.

My code basically looks like this

```
List<CustomThings> serverInfos = ServerInfos;
serverInfos.AsParallel().ForAll(srvInfo =>
{
    SoapHttpClientProtocol soapProxy = CreateProxy(srvInfo);
    //call make soap calls through the soap client
    //store results in the proper places
}
```

The reason I'm doing AsParallel here is because doing several requests over HTTP in a serial fashion takes forever. I should throw in that ***this code does work, although sporadically***.

Is it possible that things are getting disposed of in  an unpredictable fashion, and PLINQ is not a good solution for what I'm trying to do here?

Is it possible that another threading issue could cause an error which makes the soap client "give up"?

### *Additional Info*

This particular  soap proxy is talking to an ArcGIS Server. Normally, you can check the server logs and see when particular requests are inititiated and if the requests failed. There is nothing showing in these logs.

---

Here's an example of an inner exception stack trace I get from the AsParallel code.

> Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   ---> **System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the
>   server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)    at
>   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   ESRI.ArcGIS.SOAP.FeatureServerProxy.Query(Int32 LayerOrTableID, String
>   DefinitionExpression, QueryFilter QueryFilter, ServiceDataOptions
>   ServiceDataOptions, String GdbVersion, Double MaximumAllowableOffset) 
>   at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.SelectQueryOperator`2.SelectQueryOperatorResults.GetElement(Int32
>   index)    at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryResults`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
>   at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedDataSource`1.ListContiguousIndexRangeEnumerator.MoveNext(T&
>   currentElement, Int32& currentKey)    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.PipelineSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork()    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work()    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object unused)    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.<.cctor>b__0(Object o)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 2):

PLINQ does not even know your connection object exists. It cannot close it.

Read the message carefully:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The server closed the connection in an unexpected way. Your client is not at fault.

Interpreting the exception precisely is an essential debugging skill. This information was right there in the exception message.

Maybe you are generating too much load. Set a sustainable degree of parallelism. The default heuristics are for CPU work, not for IO.

```
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
```

> A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

This could mean that the server does not support HTTP keep alive.

Comment: The only reason I might suspect something client-side is that I in my test case I only have 5 or 6 "CustomThings" (making the degree of parallelism only 5 or 5). The other reason is that I'm talking to a propietary 10.2 ArcGis Server which *should* (and is designed to) handle massive amounts of database/server requests.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend looking at HTTP-level errors with Fiddler. See if keep-alive is set and not obeyed. Next would be a Wireshark trace to confirm that the remote side closed the connection (using RST). The message clearly states that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are doing anything terribly wrong with `AsParallel` for your Soap HTTP requests, and i don't think it is a threading issue.

However, the parallel requests obviously push your client/server to the number of connection limits, and that is why you are seeing the connections getting closed.

I would bet your client, server or both are not configured to handle the number of concurrent connections you are issuing. That is why it works when you run the requests in serial fashion.

I guess you don't have access to server config, so one thing you could do is to control the number of parallel requests you issue to the server at the same time by setting the `ParallelEnumerable.WithDegreeOfParallelism` setting like in the following snippet:

```
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(15)
```

That way you  control the parallelism, and don't risk overloading the server with a large number of requests on a small number of connections.

Regarding the client you should make sure that you have set the max. number of concurrent client connections to an appropriate number, just to make sure that your requests can use separate connections to the server, and prevent reusing connections which could cause your Keep-Alive issues.
The server could **close the connection** if the number of requests using a connection has exceeded the keep alive max number of connections or if it exceeds the timeout settings.

You can set the client connection limit programmatically using the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` setting. E.g. you could set it to 50:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;
```

Here is an example setting max. connections to 50 using the config file:

```
<configuration> 
 <system.net> 
   <connectionManagement> 
     <add address="*" maxconnection="50" /> 
   </connectionManagement> 
 </system.net>
```

I used "50" just as an example, you should determine/calculate/measure what is the best setting for your setup.

Also make sure you are disposing your HTTP Connections properly after each request to prevent connection timeouts.